# How do I use instance variables of generic structs in traits?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a snake game with 2 types of food:

The `Fly`:

```
 struct Fly {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}
```

And the `Spider`, which disappears if not eaten in time:

```
struct Spider {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
    ticks_alive: i32,
}
```

I want them to have some convenient methods like `position(&self) -> (u32, u32)` or `proxy() -> SpiderOrFly`:

```
pub trait Food<Type> {
    fn position(&self) -> (u32, u32) {
        (self.x, self.y)
    }

    fn proxy() -> Type {
        Type { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
}
```

I'm getting errors that `x` is not a field of `&self` and that `Type` is not a struct

Is there a way to tell Rust that `Type` has to be `Fly` or `Spider` so that I can access the instance variables in the generic implementation and don't have to produce doubled code?

Comment: You can't use `self.x` and `self.y` inside the default trait implementation, because some implementation of the trait _might_ not have those fields.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is it possible to access struct fields from within a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219730/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The other problem is that you are trying to use `Type` as a constructor, but the compiler can't know what the constructor looks like for every possible concrete type there. In fact, even if that was allowed, your code would break for `Spider` because `ticks_alive` is  missing.