# Accessing a field in generic structure

Tags: generics, rust

Given this struct:

```
pub struct A {
    pub C: B,
}
```

I'm looking create Rust container with elements of `A`, and access `A.C` in that generic Rust container.  Here is such a container:

```
pub struct MyArray<A, C> {
    data: Vec<A>,
    size: usize,
}

impl<A, C> MyArray {
    // Access the value in the ith element of data
    pub fn get_value(self, i: u64) -> u64 {
        self.data[i].C
    }
}
```

Given the following struct:

```
pub struct House {
    pub num_rooms: u64, 
}
```

I want to instantiate a generic types like this:

`let h: MyArray<House, num_rooms> = MyArray(6);`

`let d: MyArray<Cat, num_lives> = MyArray(10);`

Then I want do be able to call `h.func(5)` to get the value of specified field in the 6th element of the Rust container.

I'm not sure if this is possible at all.  If it is, macros / generics are probably needed.

Comment: What you want if I guess right, is a trait, but your question is very unclear, there is no link between `struct A` and `struct MyArray<A, C>` curently. Also A is not a suitable name for a struct.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Is it possible to access struct fields from within a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219730/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: no, you cannot access a field in a generic structure.

Comment: Okay, edited the question.  It's a little different that the trait case, since I need to instantiate a type.

Comment: Still don't make any sense, please read [ask]. Also, [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Shepmaster: My understanding is that the OP is looking for something akin to *pointer-to-member* in C++. That, in C++ you can instantiate a template `MyArray<Struct, &Struct::field_name>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a getter function for the field you want to access alongside your container, e.g.

```
pub struct MyVec<A, G> {
    data: Vec<A>,
    getter: G,
}

impl<A, G, T> MyVec<A, G>
where
    G: Fn(&A) -> T,
{
    pub fn get_value(&self, i: usize) -> T {
        (self.getter)(&self.data[i])
    }
}

struct Wobble {
    gloink: u64,
}

impl Wobble {
    fn gloink(&self) -> u64 {
        self.gloink
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = MyVec {
        data: vec![Wobble { gloink: 42 }],
        getter: Wobble::gloink,
    };
    println!("{}", v.get_value(0));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=272b99c182ce7015d70d0e5242f0b9d6)