# How to avoid code duplication using traits in Rust?

Tags: rust

Image we have a code as given below:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        // self.0 += 1;
    }
}

struct S1(usize);
impl MyTrait for S1 {}

struct S2(usize);
impl MyTrait for S2 {}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S1(0);
    s.foo();
    let mut s = S2(0);
    s.foo();
}
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that the **trait** method `foo` expects its parameter to have only one argument with the `usize` type?

Comment: Do the answers to [Is it possible to access struct fields from within a trait?](/q/28219730/3650362) answer your question? If not, please [edit] your question to explain the differences.

Comment: I think a lot of the time when people ask for a feature like this, what they really want is a [generic struct specialized with different types](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6ada32367ff9d36386473f8e3c8bb7a). I have never really seen a good justification for "fields in traits".

Comment: @trentcl Thank you, [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48470287/14414945) my question.